# Is it ok to use the article 'the' before the person's name sometimes?

Tags: american-english, british-english, articles

Can we use the article 'the' before the name (Martin) in the below sentence? Generally, we do not use article before the person's name.

"Please provide the Martin's signature."

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need to mention this line in a letter.

Comment: If it's acceptable in Indian English, it's might be appropriate. In British or American English it is not. I'd place the person's title in front of the surname (last name), e.g *Please provide us with Mr _____'s signature* The receiver of the message, I presume is not Mr Martin.

Comment: You could use "the Martin signature" to refer to the signature belonging or relating to Martin: it would be common to talk about the Martin file, the Martin oeuvre, etc.

Comment: @ShivnathKashyap But *why* do you need to mention this line in a letter? Where did you get the idea for, or the idea that, you need to use the article there? Have you seen it used somewhere else? What’s the background here?

Comment: Related: [“The Jesus who said” - why is there a definite article before the proper name “Jesus”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/190987/9161)

Comment: An article (***the*** or ***a***) can't be used before the actual proper noun ***Martin***. But you *can* validly refer to ***the** signature of Martin['s]*, or ***a** signature of Mr Smith['s]*, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The Jesus who said" - why is there a definite article before the proper name "Jesus"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190987/the-jesus-who-said-why-is-there-a-definite-article-before-the-proper-name-j)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - An article certainly can be used before the proper noun *Martin* in some contexts. But not in this one.

Comment: @Dan Bron, Mr Martin is one of the customers of a company. He wants some change in her profile with the company. So, in order to process that change, the company needs his signature on the request form.

Comment: "He wants some change in _his_ profile." Just say "Please provide Mr Martin's signature."

Comment: @ShivnathKashyap That, I understand. Thank you. What I’m asking is for background on the grammar question: where did you get the idea you could or even should insert the “the”? Have you see “the <Bob> signature” before? Is it common in your local dialect of English? What makes you want to insert it there?

Comment: @Dan Bron, No I have never seen the article 'The' before a person's name until and unless we are referring to a specific person. I just saw this sentence on one of my friends computer screen. He was writing a letter. No, it is not acceptable in Indian English too.

Comment: @ShivnathKashyap Ah, ok. That helps a lot to demystify this. Thank you. Yes, your friend simply made an error.

Answer (score 5):

No, not generally.

There are cases where a noun might be the same as someone's name where this usage may appear (without context) to be confusing.

So:

> Please provide Baker's signature

Would be valid if the person's surname was "Baker"

However:

> Please provide **the** Baker's signature

Would be valid if the person's profession was a Baker.

Comment: And then it would probably not be capitalized (profession vs surname).

Comment: Except that you wouldn't use a capital B for the baker profession.

Answer (score 5):

**NO**
At least, not in the context you have provided. There is an idiomatic usage for putting "the" before a person's name, but it is usually used to clarify you are speaking about a specific person with that name.

For example, I was on a flight one time and struck up a conversation with an elderly couple. I learned during the course of the conversation that their last name was Buffett. At one point I asked them why they were travelling and they said that they were travelling to see their son James.

"James.." I replied.  "Wait, James as in Jimmy?  As in *the* [Jimmy Buffett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Buffett)?!"

"We just call him James," the woman responded.

<sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: While the story is true, it was over 20 years ago, so it's possible I got some of the details wrong.

Comment: Another upvote for a fine story, anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

If using the definite article in front of a person's name is acceptable in Indian English, it might be appropriate. But in British or American English it is not, it should be:

> Please provide Martin's signature.

It's important to note that Martin is both a common first name and family name. The sentence could create misunderstanding: is the author of the request on [first-name terms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20first-name%20terms#:%7E:text=%3A%20having%20a%20close%20personal%20relationship,first%2Dname%20terms%20with%20adversity.) or is Martin referring to a Mr, Miss or Ms Martin?

If I needed to be more polite and formal, I'd use the person's title in front of their surname (last name), e.g.

> Please provide us with Dr./ Mr. / Ms. Martin's signature.

I presume the receiver of the message is not *the* Mr or Ms Martin. (That last sentence, where *the* is stressed, is perfectly grammatical because I am asking whether it is **the same** person.)

Comment: I tried looking in the archives for posts where the definite article is used for effect in front of people's names but gave up. I simply don't have the time, but I know that post exists...somewhere, I'm sure...at least... I think so.

Comment: If a name is famous, you might say "You met **the** Isabelle Huppert?" 'the' emphasised and pronounced "thee", and be answered, "No, the Isabelle Huppert who is a nurse at my local hospital".

Comment: Update: OP [says this usage is not licensed in IndE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284089/is-it-ok-to-use-the-article-the-before-the-persons-name-sometimes#comment530635_284089) either.